# How does this program work?

Tags: c++, c, memory, printf, endianness

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    float a = 1234.5f;
    printf("%d\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

It displays a `0`!! How is that possible? What is the reasoning?

---

I have deliberately put a `%d` in the `printf` statement to study the behaviour of `printf`.

Answer (score 239, accepted):

That's because `%d` expects an `int` but you've provided a float.

Use `%e`/`%f`/`%g` to print the float.

---

On why 0 is printed: The floating point number is converted to `double` before sending to `printf`. The number 1234.5 in double representation in little endian is

```
00 00 00 00  00 4A 93 40
```

A `%d` consumes a 32-bit integer, so a zero is printed. (As a test, you could `printf("%d, %d\n", 1234.5f);` You could get on output `0,  1083394560`.)

---

As for why the `float` is converted to `double`, as the prototype of printf is `int printf(const char*, ...)`, from 6.5.2.2/7,

> The ellipsis notation in a function prototype declarator causes argument type conversion to stop after the last declared parameter. **The default argument promotions are performed on trailing arguments.**

and from 6.5.2.2/6,

> If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that does not include a prototype, the integer promotions are performed on each argument, **and arguments that have type `float` are promoted to `double`.** These are called the *default argument promotions*.

(Thanks Alok for finding this out.)

Comment: +1 Best answer. It answers both "standard technically correct" why and "your likely implementation" why.

Comment: I believe you are the only one of 12 people who actually provided the answer he was looking for.

Comment: @KennyTM: why is floating point number converted to `double` before sending to `printf`?

Comment: Because `printf` is a variadic function, and the standard says that for variadic functions, a `float` is converted to `double` before passing.

Comment: I just checked the book (Stroustup). It says that this (conversion from float to double) only happens if `"the arguement has not been declared"`. In my example -  I have declared `a`. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: From the C standard: "The ellipsis notation in a function prototype declarator causes argument type conversion to stop after the last declared parameter. The default argument promotions are performed on trailing arguments." and "...and arguments that have type float are promoted to double. These are called the *default argument promotions*."

Comment: The very fact that one can write `printf("%d, %d\n", 1234.5f);` makes me extremely wary of the method...

Comment: @Matthieu: gcc by default would throw warnings if the format string and the input parameters' types do not match.

Comment: Keeping all this in mind, how does a `printf("%f\n", a); //%f instead of %d` manage to print `1234.500000`? Shouldn't it also be printing a `0.000000`?

Comment: @dksjalk: `%f` consumes a double (64-bit) instead of an int.

Comment: @KennyTM: thanks! I just realised that there are no separate string formats for printing single precision (`float`) and double precision (`double`) floating point (for use with `printf`)

Comment: Using incorrect format specifier in `printf()` invokes **Undefined Behaviour**.

Comment: @dksjalk: this is because `printf` cannot be passed a `float`.  By the time `printf` sees it, it's already a `double`.

Comment: **A %d consumes a 32-bit integer, so a zero is printed** >> couldn't understand this, please help, thanks

Comment: On x86_64 integers and floating point numbers are passed in different registers. So, it would print an indeterminate value instead of treating a double like an int.

Comment: When you say `%d` consumes a 32-bit integer, you mean it consumes the 4 bytes in that representation of 1234.5?

Comment: And those 4 bytes are all zeros? But why is the number being represented that way (backwards)?

Comment: @0x499602D2: (1) Yes. (2) a. Because of little-endian; b. Check IEEE-754.

Comment: But running the program multiple times, gives different answers. If the number was really represented in IEEE754 format, then the first 4 bytes should return same value. How do you explain this?

Answer (score 45):

Technically speaking there is no *the* `printf`, each library implements its own, and therefore, your method of trying to study `printf`'s behavior by doing what you are doing is not going to be of much use.  You could be trying to study the behavior of `printf` on your system, and if so, you should read the documentation, and look at the source code for `printf` if it is available for your library.

For example, on my Macbook, I get the output `1606416304` with your program.

Having said that, when you pass a `float` to a variadic function, the `float` is passed as a `double`.  So, your program is equivalent to having declared `a` as a `double`.

To examine the bytes of a `double`, you can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376915/how-to-print-out-the-memory-contents-of-a-variable-in-c/2376921#2376921) to a recent question here on SO.

Let's do that:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    double a = 1234.5f;
    unsigned char *p = (unsigned char *)&a;
    size_t i;

    printf("size of double: %zu, int: %zu\n", sizeof(double), sizeof(int));
    for (i=0; i < sizeof a; ++i)
        printf("%02x ", p[i]);
    putchar('\n');
    return 0;
}
```

When I run the above program, I get:

```
size of double: 8, int: 4
00 00 00 00 00 4a 93 40
```

So, the first four bytes of the `double` turned out to be 0, which may be why you got `0` as the output of your `printf` call.

For more interesting results, we can change the program a bit:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    double a = 1234.5f;
    int b = 42;

    printf("%d %d\n", a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

When I run the above program on my Macbook, I get:

```
42 1606416384
```

With the same program on a Linux machine, I get:

```
0 1083394560
```

Comment: Why did you program print backwards? Am I missing something? If b is a int = 42, and '%d' is the integer format, why isn't it the second printed value, since it's the second variable in the printf arguments? Is this a typo?

Comment: Probably because `int` arguments are passed in different registers than `double` arguments.  `printf` with `%d` takes the `int` argument that's 42 and the second `%d` probably prints junk since there wasn't a second `int` argument.

Answer (score 20):

The `%d` specifier tells `printf` to expect an integer. So the first four (or two, depending on the platform) bytes of the float are intepreted as an integer. If they happen to be zero, a zero is printed

The binary representation of 1234.5 is something like

```
1.00110100101 * 2^10 (exponent is decimal ...)
```

With  a C compiler which represents `float` actually as IEEE754 double values, the bytes would be (if I made no mistake)

```
01000000 10010011 01001010 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

On an Intel (x86) system with little endianess (i.e. the least significant byte coming first), this byte sequence gets reversed so that the first four bytes are zero. That is, what `printf` prints out ...

See [This Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Internal_representation) for floating point representation according to IEEE754.

Answer (score 8):

Because you invoked undefined behaviour: you violated the contract of the printf() method by lying to it about its parameter types, so the compiler is free to do whatever it pleases. It could make the program output "dksjalk is a ninnyhead!!!" and technically it would still be right.

Answer (score 7):

It's because of the representation of a float in binary. The conversion to an integer leaves it with 0.

Comment: You seem to be the only one that understood what he was asking for. Unless Im mistaken myself of course.

Comment: I agree that the answer is inaccurate and incomplete, but not wrong.

Answer (score 5):

The reason is that `printf()` is a pretty dumb function. It does not check types at all. If you say the first argument is an `int` (and this is what you are saying with `%d`), it believes you and it takes just the bytes needed for an `int`. In this case, asuming your machine uses four-byte `int` and eight-byte `double` (the `float` is converted to a `double` inside `printf()`), the first four bytes of `a` will be just zeroes, and this gets printed.

Answer (score 3):

It won't convert automatically float to integer. Because both has different format of storage. So if you want to convert, use (int) typecasting.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    float a = 1234.5f;
    printf("%d\n", (int)a);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged it with C++ as well, [this code](http://codepad.org/oBfZXj25) does the conversion as you probably expect:

```
#include <iostream.h>

int main() {
    float a = 1234.5f;
    std::cout << a << " " << (int)a << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1234.5 1234
```

Answer (score 1):

`%d` is decimal

`%f` is float

see more of these [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/).

**You are getting 0 because floats and integers are represented differently.**

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use the appropriate format specifier (%d,%f,%s,etc.) with the relevant data type (int,float, string, etc.).

Comment: The question is not how to fix it but why it works the way it works.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an integer. Try using `%f`.

Comment: I guess the question is, why doesn't it just convert the float to int and display "1234"?

Comment: don't expect c not to let you do something that makes no logical sense.  Yes many languages would give the 1234 you may expect, and maybe even some implementations of c will i don't think this behavior is defined. C lets you hang yourself its like the parent that lets you try crack for the hell of it.

Comment: Because C is designed to be flexible.

Answer (score 0):

You want %f not %d

Answer (score 0):

hey it had to print something so it printed a 0.
Remember in C 0 is everything else!

Comment: How is it so?  In C there is no such thing as everything else.

Comment: if x is something, then !x == 0 :)

Comment: if(iGot=="everything") print **"everything"; else** print "nothing";