# input-output in C

Tags: c, floating-point, printf

```
double d;
scanf("%f", &d);
printf("%f", d);
```

result:

> input: 10.3
>
> output: 0.00000

Why? i think output should be 10.3
visual studio 2008.

Comment: now that your problem is solved, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2377733/how-does-this-program-work might clarify things a bit more!

Answer (score 9):

For `scanf()`, `%f` is for a `float`. For `double`, you need `%lf`. So,

```
#include <stdio.h>
main() {
    double d; 
    scanf("%lf", &d); 
    printf("%f\n", d);
}
```

with input `10.3` produces `10.300000`.

Comment: +1 for %4.1lf format string Sergey could view this: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/

Comment: `%lf` is needed for `scanf()`, but for `printf()`, `%f` means `double` (and works with `float` too, because `float` is promoted to `double` in the variable portion of the argument list).  `%lf` is meaningless to `printf()`.

Comment: printf is a vararg function, so argument promotion need not apply - compiler does not know argument types beyond format string. Said that, %lf is needed.

Comment: el.pescado: There are a particular set of argument promotions that are always applied to arguments in the variable portion of the argument list (they are the same as those applied to the arguments of a function declared without a prototype).

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `%f` with `%lf`. `%f` is used when dealing with `float`, not `double`.
(or alternately, you could make `d` a `float`).