# Two decimal places using printf( )

Tags: c++, c, printf, decimal

I'm trying to write a number to two decimal places using `printf()` as follows:

```
#include <cstdio>
int main()
{
  printf("When this number: %d is assigned to 2 dp, it will be: 2%f ", 94.9456, 94.9456);
  return 0;
}
```

When I run the program, I get the following output:

```
# ./printf
When this number: -1243822529 is assigned to 2 db, it will be: 2-0.000000
```

Why is that?

Thanks.

Comment: the -1234... part is the representation of your 32 bit floating point as an integer. The second part is wrong you should have %2.2f, but still I can't explain the -0.0000... part. I for one get a correct result except that running your code puts an extra 2 in front of the float.

Comment: @nvm: The zeroes appear because 94.9456 was pushed onto the stack as a double (8 bytes), and the %d processed the first 4 bytes as an integer, and the next 4 bytes were zeroes, and the code then read those 4 trailing bytes from the first number plus the leading 4 bytes of the second float and tried to treat it as a double.  The answer was so small that the fixed-point format treats it as zero.  And this was run on an Intel chip, not a RISC machine.

Comment: Seems that putting an integer before "f" like that "%10f" does not have any effec, as it is just like writing "%f"? I tried that and just get the result as if it where "%f".

Answer (score 181, accepted):

What you want is `%.2f`, not `2%f`.

Also, you might want to replace your `%d` with a `%f` ;)

```
#include <cstdio>
int main()
{
printf("When this number: %f is assigned to 2 dp, it will be: %.2f ", 94.9456, 94.9456);
return 0;
}
```

This will output:

> When this number: 94.945600 is assigned to 2 dp, it will be: 94.95

See here for a full description of the printf formatting options: [`printf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/printf)

Answer (score 7):

Use: `"%.2f"` or variations on that.

See the [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html) spec for an authoritative specification of the `printf()` format strings.  Note that it separates POSIX extras from the core C99 specification.  There are some C++ sites which show up in a Google search, but some at least have a dubious reputation, judging from comments seen elsewhere on SO.

Since you're coding in C++, you should probably be avoiding `printf()` and its relatives.

Answer (score 5):

For `%d` part refer to this [How does this program work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2377733/how-does-this-program-work) and for decimal places use `%.2f`