# Adding two zeroes after decimal output

Tags: c++, double, decimal-point

I've looked this up and I haven't gotten anything to work yet, but basically I need this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  ifstream inFile;
  ofstream outFile;

  string firstName, lastName, department;
  double salary, bonus, taxes;
  double distance, timeTravel;
  int coffeeCups;
  double cupCost;
  double paycheck, aveSpeed, salesAmount;

  inFile.open("inData.txt");
  outFile.open("outData.txt");

  inFile >> firstName >> lastName >> department;
  inFile >> salary >> bonus >> taxes;
  inFile >> distance >> timeTravel;
  inFile >> coffeeCups >> cupCost;

  paycheck = salary + salary*(bonus/100) - ((salary+ salary*(bonus/100))*(taxes/100));
  aveSpeed = distance/timeTravel;
  salesAmount = coffeeCups * cupCost;

  outFile << "Name: " << firstName << " " << lastName << ", Department: " << department << endl;
 
  outFile << "Monthly gross salary: $" << salary << ", Monthly bonus: " << bonus << "%" << ", Taxes: " << taxes << "%" << endl;
 
  outFile << "Paycheck: $" << paycheck << endl << endl;
 
  outFile << "Distance traveled: " << distance << " miles, Traveling time: " << timeTravel << " hours" << endl;
 
  outFile << "Average speed: " << aveSpeed << " miles per hour" << endl << endl;

  outFile << "Number of coffee cups sold: " << coffeeCups << ", Cost: $" << cupCost << " per cup" << endl;
 
  outFile << "Sales amount = $" << salesAmount;

  inFile.close();
  outFile.close();
  
  return 0;
}
```

to output this:

```
Name: Giselle Robinson, Department: Accounting
Monthly Gross Salary: $5600.00, Monthly Bonus: 5.00%, Taxes: 30.00%
Paycheck: $4116.00

Distance Traveled: 450.00 miles, Traveling Time: 9.00 hours
Average Speed: 50.00 miles per hour

Number of Coffee Cups Sold: 75, Cost: $1.50 per cup
Sales Amount = $112.50
```

but instead, I'm getting this:

```
Name: Giselle Robinson, Department: Accounting
Monthly gross salary: $5600, Monthly bonus: 5%, Taxes: 30%
Paycheck: $4116

Distance traveled: 450 miles, Traveling time: 9 hours
Average speed: 50 miles per hour

Number of coffee cups sold: 75, Cost: $1.5 per cup
Sales amount = $112.5
```

Comment: Look at the [`std::fixed`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed) and [`std::setprecision()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) stream modifiers

Comment: Remy has best c++ answer. For a C answer see [printf formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784336/two-decimal-places-using-printf)

Answer (score 3):

```
// Add this before you start writing to the file
outFile << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << std::setfill('0');

// Your original output code below
outFile << "Name: " << firstName << " " << lastName << ", Department: " << department << endl;
...
```

credit https://stackoverflow.com/a/15327758/10808581

Answer (score 0):

**Here is some sample code; I hope you will find it useful.**

```
   stringstream ssdd;
   ssdd.str("");
   double aa=243.765;

   ssdd << "------------" << std::endl;
   ssdd << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << aa << std::endl; 
   ssdd << std::fixed << std::setprecision(3) << aa << std::endl;
   ssdd << std::fixed << std::setprecision(4) << aa << std::endl;
   std::cout << ssdd.str();
   std::cout << "------------";
```

**Output is:**

```
------------
243.76
243.765
243.7650
------------
```