# C++ union to represent data memory vs C scalar variable type

Tags: c++, c, floating-point, integer, unions

Today I've a weird question.

**The Code(C++)**

```
#include <iostream>

union name
{
    int num;
    float num2;

}oblong;


int main(void)
{
    oblong.num2 = 27.881;

    std::cout << oblong.num << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**The Code(C)**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    float num = 27.881;

    printf("%d\n" , num);

    return 0;
}
```

**The Question**

1. As we know, C++ unions can hold more than one type of data element but only one type at a time. So basically the `name oblong` will only reserve one portion of memory which is 32-bit (because the biggest type in the union is 32-bit, int and float) and this portion could either hold a integer or float.
2. So I just assign a value of 27.881 into `oblong.num2` (as you can see on the above code). But out of curiosity, I access the memory using `oblong.num` which is pointing to the same memory location.
3. As expected, it gave me a value which is not 27 because the way float and integer represented inside a memory is different, that's why when I use `oblong.num` to access the memory portion it'll treat that portion of memory value as integer and interpret it using integer representation way.
4. I know this phenomena also will happen in C , that's why I initialize a float type variable with a value and later on read it using the `%d`.So I just try it out by using the same value `27.881` which you can see above. But when I run it, something weird happens, that is the value of the one I get in C is different from C++.
5. Why does this happen? From what I know the two values I get from the two codes in the end are not garbage values, but why do I get different values? I also use the sizeof to verified both C and C++ integer and float size and both are 32-bit. So memory size isn't the one that causes this to happen, so what prompt this difference in values?

Comment: Same case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2377733/how-does-this-program-work
and this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398791/how-is-conversion-of-float-double-to-int-handled-in-printf

Comment: The difference isn't C versus C++. You could compile the second example in C++ too, and get the same result from C and C++. The first example with the `union` would need a small change to use `printf`, instead of `std::cout<<`, but after that you'd get the same results from C and C++ again.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, having the wrong `printf()` format string is undefined behavior. Now that said, here is what is actually happening in your case:

In vararg functions such as `printf()`, integers smaller than `int` are promoted to `int` and floats smaller than `double` are promoted to `double`.

The result is that your `27.881` is being converted to an 8-byte double as it is passed into `printf()`. Therefore, the binary representation is no longer the same as a `float`.

Format string `%d` expects a 4-byte integer. So in effect, you will be printing the lower 4-bytes of the double-precision representation of `27.881`. (assuming little-endian)

*Actually (assuming strict-FP), you are seeing the bottom 4-bytes of `27.881` after it is cast to `float`, and then promoted to `double`.

Answer (score 2):

In both cases you are encountering undefined behaviour. Your implementation just happens to do something strange.

Comment: Both cases? I thought only the second printf is undefined. The first is a dump with a well defined bitpattern comming from the float. (For what it makes sense is another question of course)

Comment: The first case is UB because you're accessing the object `float(27.881)` via an expression of type `int`. Objects must be accessed either via an expression of their own type, or via (unsigned) `char[]`. The latter rule is so you can `memcpy` objects (in C; C++ restricts `memcpy` to Plain Old Data).