# How numbers are stored?

Tags: c++

What kind of method does the compiler use to store numbers? One char is 0-255. Two chars side by side are 0-255255. In c++ one short is 2 bytes. The size is 0-65535. Now, how does the compiler convert 255255 to 65535 and what happens with the - in the unsigned numbers?

Comment: It's not 255255, it's (255 * 2^8) + 255.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_%28computer_science%29

Comment: You just did something a bit like saying `123 + 456 = 123456`, which is clearly wrong. You don't just concatenate numbers when you're doing maths.

Comment: if I store the number 7665 on a short, what's the 1st byte and what's the 2nd?

Comment: It depends on the system. On [little-endian platforms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), the first byte is 241 and the second byte 29. On big-endian platforms it's the other way around.

Comment: ObSocraticMethod: If 0..255 has a range of 256 numbers, how many numbers can 256 ranges of 256 numbers hold?  I.e. what is 256*256?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have got the math totally wrong. Here's how it really is

since each bit can only take on either of two states only(1 and 0) , n bits as a whole can represents 2^n different ***quantities*** not numbers. When dealing with integers a standard short integer size of 2 bytes can represent 2^n - 1 (n=16   so  65535)which are mapped to decimal numbers in real life for compuational simplicity. 

When dealing with 2 character they are two seperate entities (string is an array of characters). There are many ways to read the two characters on a whole, if you read is at as a string then it would be same as two seperate characters side by side. let me give you an example :
remember i will be using hexadecimal notation for simplicity! 
if you have doubt mapping ASCII characters to hex take a look at this [ascii to hex](http://asciitable.com)

for simplicity let us assume the characters stored in two adjacent positions are both A.
Now hex code for A is 0x41 so the memory would look like

1 byte  .......  2nd byte   
01000100 01000001

if you were to read this from the memory as a string and print it out then the output would be 
AA

if you were to read the whole 2 bytes as an integer then this would represent

0 * 2^15 + 1 * 2^14 + 0 * 2^13 + 0 * 2^12 + 0 * 2^11 + 1 * 2^10 + 0 * 2^9 + 0 * 2^8 + 0 * 2^7 + 1 * 2^6 + 0 * 2^5 + 0 * 2^4 + 0 * 2^3 + 0 * 2^2 + 0 * 2^1 + 1 * 2^0

> =  17537

if unsigned integers were used then the 2 bytes of data would me mapped to integers between 
0 and 65535 but if the same represented a signed value then then , though the range remains the same the biggest positive number that can be represented would be 32767. the values would lie between -32768 and 32767  this is because all of the 2 bytes cannot be used and the highest order bit is left to determine the sign. 1 represents negative and 2 represents positive.

You must also note that type conversion (two characters read as single integer) might not always give you the desired results , especially when you narrow the range. (example a doble precision float is converted to an integer.)

For more on that see this answer [double to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2377733/how-does-this-program-work)

hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

The maximum value you can store in n bits (when the lowest value is 0 and the values represented are a continuous range), is 2ⁿ − 1.  For 8 bits, this gives 255. For 16 bits, this gives 65535.

Your mistake is thinking that you can just concatenate 255 with 255 to get the maximum value in two `char`s - this is definitely wrong. Instead, to get from the range of 8 bits, which is 256, to the range of 16 bits, you would do 256 × 256 = 65536. Since our first value is 0, the maximum value is 65535, once again.

Note that a `char` is only guaranteed to have *at least* 8 bits and a `short` at least 16 bits (and must be at least as large as a `char`).

Comment: `char` is _not_ guaranteed to have 8 bits.  I've seen 9 bit `char`, and I've heard that some modern machines have 16 or 32 bit `char`.

Comment: @JamesKanze For some reason I thought `CHAR_BIT` must be exactly 8, even though its in the same "equal or greater" list as `USHRT_MAX`. Thanks.

Comment: There's also no guarantee (except for `unsigned char`) that all of the bits participate in the value.  On at least one machine (still in production), `int` is 48 bits, but only 40 are used.

Comment: How do you think they implemented C and C++ on 36 bit machines.  (I think the last 36 bit machine went out of production a few years ago, but they used to be quite common.)

Comment: @JamesKanze But there must be at least enough bits participating in the value to meet the minimum maximum value requirements.

Comment: Of course.  The only case I actually know where not all of the bits participate is a 48 bit tagged architecture, where `int` and `double` have the same representation, with the exponent field being 0 implying `int`.  (Overflow of integral arithmetic results in a value that will be treated as a float, even if it is assigned to an `int` variable.)

Answer (score 2):

When using decimal system it's true that range of one digit is 0-9 and range of two digits is 0-99. When using hexadecimal system the same thing applies, but you have to do the math in hexadecimal system. Range of one hexadecimal digit is 0-Fh, and range of two hexadecimal digits (one byte) is 0-FFh. Range of two bytes is 0-FFFFh, and this translates to 0-65535 in decimal system.

Comment: +1 For catching what they were probably thinking.

Answer (score 2):

Decimal is a base-10 number system. This means that each successive digit from right-to-left represents an incremental power of 10. For example, `123` is `3 + (2*10) + (1*100)`. You may not think of it in these terms in day-to-day life, but that's how it works.

Now you take the same concept from decimal (base-10) to binary (base-2) and now each successive digit is a power of 2, rather than 10. So `1100` is `0 + (0*2) + (1*4) + (1*8)`.

Now let's take an 8-bit number (`char`); there are 8 digits in this number so the maximum value is `255` `(2**8 - 1)`, or another way, `11111111 == 1 + (1*2) + (1*4) + (1*8) + (1*16) + (1*32) + (1*64) + (1*128)`.

When there are another 8 bits available to make a 16-bit value, you just continue counting powers of 2; you don't just "stick" the two `255`s together to make `255255`. So the maximum value is `65535`, or another way, `1111111111111111 == 1 + (1*2) + (1*4) + (1*8) + (1*16) + (1*32) + (1*64) + (1*128) + (1*256) + (1*512) + (1*1024) + (1*2048) + (1*4096) + (1*8192) + (1*16384) + (1*32768)`.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the type: integral types must be stored as binary
(or at least, appear so to a C++ program), so you have one bit
per binary digit.  With very few exceptions, all of the bits are
significant (although this is not required, and there is at
least one machine where there are extra bits in an `int`).  On
a typical machine, `char` will be 8 bits, and if it isn't
signed, can store values in the range `[0,2^8)`; in other words,
between 0 and 255 inclusive.  `unsigned short` will be 16 bits
(range `[0,2^16)`), `unsigned int` 32 bits (range `[0,2^32)`)
and `unsigned long` either 32 or 64 bits.

For the signed values, you'll have to use at least one of the
bits for the sign, reducing the maximum positive value.  The
exact representation of negative values can vary, but in most
machines, it will be 2's complement, so the ranges will be
`signed char:`[-2^7,2^7-1)`, etc.

If you're not familiar with base two, I'd suggest you learn it
very quickly; it's fundamental to how all modern machines store
numbers.  You should find out about 2's complement as well: the
usual human representation is called sign plus magnitude, and is
very rare in computers.