# Efficient conversion of float endianness in strict portable C

Tags: c, optimization, floating-point, endianness

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2782725/converting-float-values-from-big-endian-to-little-endian) is good because it is very portable, correct and passes compilers set to be strict, but it is less efficient than I want and than it could be, because it doesn't use the x86 bswap instruction. (Maybe other instruction sets have similar efficient instructions.)

If the system I'm running on supports `ntohl()` then I would expect `ntohl()` to use the bswap instruction and gets me close. `ntohl()` does exactly the right thing, but it only works on uint32_t, not on a float.  Casting between a uint32_t and a float is type punning and not allowed by strict compilers. Making a union with a float and a uint32_t runs into undefined compiler behavior (per previous posts here).

My understanding from previous posts is that casting from any pointer type to a char * or vice versa is explicitly allowed. So what is wrong with this solution? I haven't seen it mentioned in any answers yet.

```
char NetworkOrderFloat[4]; // Assume it contains network-order float bytes

uint32_t HostOrderInt = ntohl(*(uint32_t *)NetworkOrderFloat);

char *Pointer = (char *)&HostOrderInt;

float HostOrderFloat = *(float *)Pointer;
```

The ideal solution here seems to be more environments supporting ntohf(), but that doesn't seem to have happened yet.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7396744/2702398

Comment: “Making a union with a float and a uint32_t runs into undefined compiler behavior (per previous posts here)” not really, it's explicitly allowed by footnote 82 that was added in C99TC3 and preserved in later C standards. It is certainly **implementation-defined** behavior.

Comment: "Making a union with a float and a uint32_t runs into undefined compiler behavior (per previous posts here)" is not a problem with C as tagged here.  That previous post is a C++ one and a union is a problem there.

Comment: What is the point being strictly portable when the floating-point representation is not guaranteed portable ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust: Code that has one constraint (implementation must use IEEE-754) is more readily usable than code that has two constraints (implementation must use IEEE-754 and must be little-endian).

Answer (score 3):

Your proposal breaks “strict aliasing rules”, the first time when it does `*(uint32_t *)NetworkOrderFloat`. The expression `(uint32_t *)NetworkOrderFloat` is still the address of an array of chars, and accessing it with an lvalue of type `uint32_t` is against these rules. Details and more examples can be found in [this article](https://trust-in-soft.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/vmcai.pdf).

Using a `union` to convert a float's representation to `uint32_t`, on the other hand, is not forbidden by the C standard as far as I know. But you can always use `memcpy` if you worry that it is.

```
float NetworkOrderFloat = ...;
uint32_t tmp;
_Static_assert(sizeof(uint32_t)==sizeof(float),"unsupported arch");
memcpy(&tmp, &NetworkOrderFloat, sizeof(float));
tmp = ntohl(tmp);
memcpy(&HostOrderFloat, &tmp, sizeof(float));
```

A decent modern compiler [should compile](https://godbolt.org/g/NEMy7A) the `memcpy` calls to nothing and `ntohl` to `bswap`.