# Problems reading a binary file with fread function

Tags: c, stdin, fread

What I want to do is to read the contents of a '.d' binary file and store them in an array.
So I wrote the following codes:

```
void viewFile()
{
   unsigned char inFileData[SIZE];
   char fileName[SIZE];
   int numRead;

   FILE *inBinFile;


    printf("Enter the file name:");
    scanf("%s", fileName);

    inBinFile = fopen( fileName, "rb");
        if(( inBinFile = fopen(fileName, "rb")) == NULL )
        {
           fprintf( stderr, "Error opening %s\n", fileName );
           clearStdin();/*a function to clear stdin*/
           mainMenu();/*a function to prompt user input*/
        }
    numRead = fread( inFileData, sizeof(unsigned char), SIZE, inBinFile );
    inFileData[SIZE] = '\0';

    printf("U coded data:\n%s\n", inFileData);
    printf("%d\n", numRead);

    fclose(inBinFile);
   return;
}
```

the output is an unreadable pile of junk. Which part did I do wrong? I don't get it.

also, I wrote my clearStdin function as below:

```
void clearStdin(void)
{
    scanf("%*[^\n]");
    scanf("%*1[\n]");
   return;
}
```

compiler reported no errors, but somehow the function call doesn't seem to work exactly the way I wanted. It did clear stdin, but there are always errors closely following wherever this function is called, eg., the mainmenu function to prompt user input.

Please help!! thanks in advance.

Comment: Unless the contents of a binary file is a readable set of ASCII characters, sending the contents to `stdout` using a `%s` `printf()` format should generally result in an unreadable pile of junk.   What is actually in the file?

Comment: What else would you expect - you said yourself the file was binary and so why would it yield readable output?

Comment: Is there a reason you open the file twice?

Comment: Micheal, the actual content is just 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9. That's where I got confused.. thanks!

Comment: mathematician1975 the design specification said that the content is 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9, so i want to print it... sorry for not making it clear enough and thank you!

Comment: Joachim Pileborg I shall fix that bug :) thank you

Comment: `inFileData[SIZE] = '\0';`  out-of-bounds access

Comment: did that. BLUEPIXY  thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

"the output is an unreadable pile of junk" - yes, it *will* be. It's a binary file, it's not meant to be readable as text.

If you want to see binary information in a readable form, think about doing a hex dump of it.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376915/how-to-print-out-the-memory-contents-of-a-variable-in-c/2377115#2377115) for a way to do this.